# Fundamental homomorphism theorem (epimorphism)

Tags: ring-theory, epimorphisms

> Let φ : R → S be a ring epimorphism. Prove that R/kerφ ∼= S.

Is this the fundamental homomorphism theorem? I thought the FHT started with a ring homomorphism and not an epimorphism. Does this change the proof of the theorem ?

Comment: If $\varphi$ is epi-, then what is $\mathrm {Im}\, \varphi$ in the FHT then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula for the homomorphism theorem is
$$R/\ker(\phi)\cong \mathrm{Im}(\phi)$$
In the special case, $\phi$ is an epimorphism, then $\mathrm{Im}(\phi)=S$, but be careful, you cannot deduce the general formula from the special case, for example when $\phi$ isn‘t an epimorphism

Answer (score 0):

You can state the theorem without the epimorphism assumption replacing $S$ by $\mathrm{Im} \varphi$. So both formulation are equivalent.

Comment: Okay thank you !